# Retrofit 2 как изменить запрос динамический?

Tags: android, retrofit

```
@GET("?act=object&cid=10&sort=1&limit=10")
Call<ResResponse> getResturantList(@Query("page") String page);


ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResResponse> call = apiInterface.getResturantList("1");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResResponse> call, Response<ResResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                ResResponse resResponse = response.body();
                Info info = resResponse.getInfo().get(0);
                List<Resturant> resturants = info.getResturant();
                loadingView.hideLoading();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new ResturantAdapter(resturants, R.layout.card_view_resturant,getApplicationContext()));

            }
            else{
                try {

                    Log.i("Main Activity", response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("resturant",t.toString());

        }
    });
}
```

когда scroll доходить в конец recyclerview,page должен увеличиваться на один и показать следующий 10 элементов
`

Answer (score 1):

Это называется пагинация. Вот ссылка [endlessscroll recyclerview](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)
на реализацию.